# Observable.combineLatest continue even if one fails

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function that needs to resolve multiple documents from firebase

```
  fetchDocuments(documentIds: string[]): Observable<TreeNodeDocument[]> {
    const observables = [];
    for(let id of documentIds){
      observables.push(this.fetchDocument(id));
    }
    return Observable.combineLatest(observables, (...docs: TreeNodeDocument[]) => {
      //some transformations on the resolved documents
      return docs;
    });
  }
```

`this.fetchDocument(id)` returns an observable of type `TreeNodeDocument`.

This function works as long as all of the documents can be resolved. Now sometimes it happens that some of the documents cannot be resolved, then the respective  `fetchDocument(id)` observable will fail. It is ok and expected that some of the documents cannot be resolved. However the `Observable.combineLatest` fails completely if one of them fails (I understand this is a good default behaviour).

My question is now, can I use `combineLatest` in a way so I get only the documents on which the fetch has worked and just ignore the ones on which it failed? Or can I achieve this in a different way?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pipe each source Observable (each `this.fetchDocument(id)`) with `catchError` that will replace the `error` notification with a dummy `next` item (or whatever you want).

```
for (let id of documentIds){
  observables.push(this.fetchDocument(id).pipe(
    catchError(() => of(null)),
  ));
}

...
```

Note, that you can't use just `empty()` or `of()` because both of them wouldn't emit any `next` item and `combineLatest` wouldn't work as you expect. Of course, instead of `null` you can use anything you want. The array of docs will have `null` at indices where a source Observable failed.