# CombineLatest continues even when one fails and already has a pipe for catchError

Tags: angular, rxjs

What I want to achieve is very similar to what is described here: [Observable.combineLatest continue even if one fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260559/observable-combinelatest-continue-even-if-one-fails)

The major different, is that my service already has a component to handle error requests which return a throwError.

**Service:**

```
get(): Observable<Array<MyObject>> {
    return this.client.get<Array<MyObject>>('/api').pipe(
      map(response => this.flattenMyObject(response)),
      catchError(ServiceHandler.error)
    );
  }
```

Both calls are just like the above, just different endpoints

**ServiceHandler:**

```
export namespace ServiceHandler {
  export function error(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${err.status}, ` + `body was: ${err.error}`
      );
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

And the **Component:**

```
    const observable1$ = this.myService.get()
      .pipe(take(1));
    const observable2$ = this.myService.getOther().pipe(take(1));

    const result$ = zip(observable1$, observable2$).pipe(
      map(([list1, list2]) => {
        let concatenedList = [];

        const hasList1 = !!list1 && list1.length > 0;
        const hasList2 = !!list2 && list2.length > 0;

        if (hasList1) {
          concatenedList = concatenedList.concat(list1);
        }

        if (hasList2) {
          concatenedList = concatenedRulesList.concat(list2);
        }

        return concatenedList;
      })
    );
    this.gridData$ = result$;
  }
```

The problem is that as it is, when one of the calls fails, the first one will be cancelled and nothing will be returned. If in my Service I change the catchError to: `catchError(() => of(null))`, then when one the calls fails, the output is not affected and the results from the successful call is loaded on my class variable `gridData$`.

The same behavior happens if I use `.zip`, `.forkjoin` or `.combineLatest`. Any of these would work for my requirement.

Suggestions?

Comment: return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');  
because you return throwing not an Observable

Comment: might you rephrase your question? I didn't get what you want to achieve. If you want to keep your catchError, but in the same time to keep combineLatest working even there's an error - simply add one `catchError(() => of(null))` right after the first `catchError`. If you don't want to get `null`, try `EMPTY` instead of `of(null)`.

Comment: you must return an error return of(new Error('Something bad happened; please try again later.'))

Comment: EMPTY ('never') returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is you want the code carry on after logging the error as if there is no error right? 
your service is already handling the error, and then forwarding the error, then your component can catch the forwarded error, ignore it, and emit and empty list, everything should work as expected, since you are ignoring the thrown error, also, I would use combineLatest for this scenario, unless you are strictly looking to maintain the emitted values sequence

```
   const observable1$ = this.myService.get()
                  .pipe(
                        take(1),
                        catchError(_ => of([]))
                   );

    const observable2$ = this.myService.getOther()
                  .pipe(
                        take(1),
                        catchError(_ => of([]))
                  );



 this.gridData$ = combineLatest(observable1$, observable2$)
                  .pipe(
                        map(([list1, list2]) => [...list1,...list2])
                   );
```